# SMART support is: Unavailable - Packet Interface Devices [this device: Reserved] don't support ATA SMART

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smartmontools

So, I have a server which has 7 hardisks, each and everyone of them has smartmontools enabled, except the 7th hardisk (/dev/sdg). Tried force enabling it, did not work.

```
root@ac001.bafi:~# smartctl -a /dev/sdg
[unusually long delay]
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     CçS
Serial Number:    T- ^Rֻdª ª)EM½µr¢
Firmware Version: Q­Å{õM
User Capacity:    1,257,344,326,144 bytes [1.25 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    19867 rpm
Form Factor:      Unknown (0xf9e3)
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
...
SMART support is: Unavailable - Packet Interface Devices [this device:        
Reserved] don't support ATA SMART

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting.
```

Ran:

```
root@ac001.bafi:~# smartctl -H  /dev/sdg
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,    
www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show    if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Even tried to force enable smartctl:

```
root@ac001.bafi:~# smartctl -T permissive -s on /dev/sdg1
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,   
www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
unable to fetch IEC (SMART) mode page [unsupported field in scsi command]
```

Comment: How is the device physically connected?  Are you sure you don't have a failed disk?

Comment: either the disk is failing, the controller/firmware is at least partly broken, or the manufacturer is so far away from using the standard smart operation that it doesn't support it at all. (or it just does not have smart support, but at least for the drives i have without smart i got way different output)

Comment: ... or smartctl is not using correct translation layer to talk to it.  `-r ioctl,2` will produce verbose record of ioctl() transactions with the device -- please run it with these options and post the output somewhere.